# Regular expression of host address?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want a regular expression for javascript to validate host address like

```
http://192.168.10.10:8089/
and
www.abc.com
and 
www.abc.com.aa
```

Comment: That's nice for you, is there a question in there? Have you tried http://regexlib.com?

Comment: @Lazarus: +1 We have thougth the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking for it at [Regular Expression Library](http://www.regexlib.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

This puts a valid numeric IP address in `$1`:

```
/(\bhttp:\/\/(?:\d{1,2}\.|1\d\d\.|2[0-4]\d\.|25[0-5]\.){3}(?:1?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\b(?::\d{1,5})?)/
```

If you don't care about validation, you can use `\d{1,3}\`. for the numbers that precede a period and `\d{1,3}` for the last one.  This will run faster.

For the "`www`" URLs, this will put the URL in `$1`:

```
/(www\.\w+\.\w{3}(?:\.\w{2})?)\b/
```

Am using documentation here:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

This block of code will decompose the url

```
var fields = url.match( /(.*)[:/]{3}([^:/]+)[:]?([^/]*)([^?]*)[?]?(.*)/ );
if(fields === null){
    throw new Error('bar url');
}
var protocol = fields[1];
var host = fields[2];
var port = fields[3];
var path = fields[4];
var query = fields[5];
```

So if you get into the if, means that url is a bad composed url

Hope it helps